# Something lik Intel True Key for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, login

I like Intel True Key that lets me login by the camera and program that recognizes my face. I use that with MS-Windows 10 on a laptop (Asus UX301LA).

Now I wonder if there is something similar for Ubuntu Linux? That could let me login similarly to Intel True Key, just by photoing my face.

Comment: Watch out for the term [face unlock](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+face-unlock) – and see our Ubuntu sister site: [How can I use face-recognition to login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/155140/68291) / [Login via Face Detection](https://askubuntu.com/q/83426/68291) (and probably more). Didn't use any of those myself, hence only a comment here :)